How to use bootstrap 5 tooltips in vue js 3
I'm trying to use the bootstrap 5 tooltips in an application with vue.js 3, but I'm not able to get them to work properly.
I've tried several ways, and the only one that made the tooltips appear was the first solution given to this question: Adding Bootstrap 5 tooltip to Vue 3. But it's not just working on hover, when I click on the button where I added the tooltip, it stays "stuck" on the screen.
If anyone has had a similar problem and knows how to help, I would greatly appreciate it. I also accept suggestions for good tooltip libraries that can be used with vue.js 3, so that I can test if I can't get the ones from bootstrap 5 to work properly.
My imports in the main.js file and the page:
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import axios from "axios";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap";
import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css";

<script setup>
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { Tooltip } from "bootstrap";

const showTest = () => {
  router.push("/test");
};

onMounted(() => {
  new Tooltip(document.body, {
    selector: "[data-bs-toggle='tooltip']",
  });
});
</script>

<template>
    <button
        class="btn btn-link"
        data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
        data-bs-placement="top"
        title="Test"
        style="text-decoration: none"
        @click="showTest()"
    >
        {{ Test }}
    </button>
</template>


I couldn't figure out how to make them work, so I created a component using css and javascript.

As explained here and in other recent of my answers, Bootstrap does not support Vue3 and probably never will. So yes, you could import some components with the CSS part but you will not have the reactive part of things.
Hence, you will need to reinvent the wheel and struggle a lot to make it work. The best approach would be to follow the website I linked in the other answer for some better alternatives that fully support Vue3.

Thank you! I agree with you, if I had realized this before I wouldn't have used bootstrap 5. After many attempts and wasted time I gave up on using the bootstrap 5 tooltips, and created my tooltips using just css. If anyone else has the same problem, and decides to try the same thing to avoid using a second library, remember not to use the tooltip name in any class created to avoid conflict with the bootstrap classes. I will not mark this answer as accepted for now so that in case someone manages to reinvent the wheel, they can provide an answer that can help those who have the same problem.

@FranS reinventing the wheel as being able to plug Bootstrap 5 to Vue 3? Might not be doable in a proper decent way. Or make their own tool tips? In that case the question doesn't make sense. But I am fine both ways if it helps the next visitor to avoid trying to make Bootstrap work.
